# connection.parse not accepted in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I am trying to convert an existing rails 3 project to rails 4.
Here is part of the code which has syntax that is not acceptable in Rails 4

```
      sql = [
        "BEGIN #{Card::MY_PACKAGE}.retrieve_card(",
        my_attrs.map { |a| ":#{a}, " }.join,
        ':errormsg); END;'
      ].join

  connection = self.connection.raw_connection
  cursor = connection.parse(sql)

  my_attrs.each { |a| cursor.bind_param(a, my_attrs.send(a)) }
```

I noticed connection.parse no longer works with Rails 4(I am working with activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter)

I am trying to fully comphrend what the above code does( I didn't write it)

What would be the equivalent syntax in rails 4?

```
cursor = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql) //Something along these lines?
```

EDIT:

I get this:

```
 `"DEPRECATION WARNING: #connection is deprecated in favour of accessing it via the class."` //when i try to puts self.connection.class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to fully comp[re]hrend what the above code does( I didn't
>   write it)

```
module Card  #Creates a namespace called Card
  MY_PACKAGE = "hello"
end

str1 = "BEGIN #{Card::MY_PACKAGE}.retrieve_card("  #Looks in a namespace called Card for the constant MY_PACKAGE
puts str1  #=> "BEGIN hello.retrieve_card("

my_attrs = ['dog', 'cat', 'squirrel']
arr = my_attrs.map { |a| ":#{a}, " }
p arr      #=> [":dog, ", ":cat, ", ":squirrel, "]
str2 = arr.join('')
p str2  #=> ":dog, :cat, :squirrel,"

str3 = ':errormsg); END;'
p str3  #=> ":errormsg); END;"

array_of_strs = [str1, str2, str3]

sql_statement = array_of_strs.join('')
p sql_statement  #=> "BEGIN hello.retrieve_card(:dog, :cat, :squirrel, :errormsg); END;"
```

join(separator=$,)
Returns a string created by converting each element of the array to a string, separated by the given separator. If the separator is nil, it uses current $,. If both the separator and $, are nil, it uses empty string.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-join

> What would be the equivalent syntax in rails 4?

To me, it looks like a raw_connection should be able to call parse(), see lines 98, 107 here:

https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced/blob/8c1335658a864f93fe1e6b22a512d281677ee170/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_oci_connection.rb

The class on that page inherits from:

```
class OracleEnhancedOCIConnection < OracleEnhancedConnection
```

...and the OracleEnhancedConnection class has an attribute reader for @raw_connection, see line 17 here:

https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced/blob/8c1335658a864f93fe1e6b22a512d281677ee170/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_connection.rb

Is that the raw_connection returned by self.connection.raw_connection?  Try:

```
puts self.connection.class
```

> puts self.class.connection.raw_connection.class returns: OCI8EnhancedAutoRecover"

The `OCI8EnhancedAutoRecover` class is defined here:

https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced/blob/8c1335658a864f93fe1e6b22a512d281677ee170/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_oci_connection.rb

...like this:

```
class OCI8EnhancedAutoRecover < DelegateClass(OCI8)
```

The `OCI8EnhancedAutoRecover` class defines some methods--none of which are parse()--and delegates other method calls to the OCI8 class--that's what `< DelegateClass(OCI8)` means.

The OCI8 class is made available by:

```
require "oci8"
```

...which requires the `ruby-oci8 gem`.  That gem defines the OCI8 class here:

https://github.com/kubo/ruby-oci8/blob/master/lib/oci8/oci8.rb

And on line 168 it defines a parse() method:

```
  def parse(sql)
    @last_error = nil
    parse_internal(sql)
  end
```

So calling parse() on the raw_connection should work.

Comment: I get this  "DEPRECATION WARNING: #connection is deprecated in favour of accessing it via the class." when i try to puts self.connection.class

Comment: @Micheal, Then do: `puts self.class.connection.class`

Comment: You are correct. that returns me a `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::OracleEnhancedAdapter`

Comment: @Micheal, What do you get for: `puts self.class.connection.raw_connection.class`?

Comment: `puts self.class.connection.raw_connection.class` returns "OCI8EnhancedAutoRecover"

Comment: In that first link I posted is the code: `@raw_connection = OCI8EnhancedAutoRecover.new(....)`  and on line 98 is the code `@raw_connection.parse(..)`, so that means you can call `parse()` on your raw_connection object.  Try calling parse() with some simple SQL that you know will succeed.

Comment: `self.class.connection.raw_connection` works as opposed to `self.connection.raw_connection`